# Render-blocking Javascript and CSS

Tags: javascript

It seems to me that anytime there is a `<script src="name1.js">` or a `<link href="name2.css">` statement in the `<head>`, these two files block rendering of the markup.

FWIW, I have tried adding "async" to the `<script>` tag and it totally messes up some of my jQuery plug-ins

Given that, I really do not understand the phrase "Render-blocking Javascript and CSS".

Thanks!

Comment: Keep your CSS in `head` and JS to the end of `body`

Comment: @JohnLove it might be the issue with your importing the sequence of your js and css files

Answer (score 3):

They block rendering of markup because the browser parses the HTML file from top down.

You can avoid this by placing the `script` tag before the closing `body`:

```
  <script src="whatever.js"></script>
</body>
```

You're out of luck with `link` elements, unless you just use inline `style` declarations in the `head` (probably not a good idea).

You can also use the `async` attribute in the `script` tag, or you can use one of any numerous async JavaScript libraries.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to load the critical css first before loading the main/minified css file to avoid render blocking on CSS files.